# How to debug the application after deployed in IIs?

Tags: c#

Hai All,
I'm developing the application using .net 2008 and Oracle 10g as database. I have deployed the application in IIS, now when two users get logged into the same applicaion, same page at a time getting error as 
"****Connection must be open for this operation.Cannot access a disposed object.object name: 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OralceConnection'.Connection must be open for this operation***"*

Plz give a solution to solve this multiuser issue..

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: My guess: are you using shared connection(e.g. static) to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to look into what's happening on IIS is to deploy a debug build, connect to the machine the server is on, and run the CLR debugger. Of course, this is only really practical in a staging rather than live scenario (or you have dozens or even thousands of people hitting the breakpoint, and of course the whole thing freezes up while you are stepping through).

This case sounds a bit like you might have a connection object statically scoped, or otherwise shared between threads, rather than created as needed on each thread of execution. It's the sort of thing sometimes seen if someone tries to manually pool connection objects (which is pointless, indeed counter-productive, as the underlying connector objects are pooled for you).