# To Debug the Application that deployed in IIS

Tags: c#

How to perform Debug after the application deployed in IIS....

Comment: It's really simple : you don't :) Try de debug it in your dev machine, never on a production environment. That's what dev machine are made for : debugging the code, and that's what production machine are made for : do the work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug the application after deployed in IIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862379/how-to-debug-the-application-after-deployed-in-iis)

Comment: @remi bourgarel - take your point, but don't forget a lot of people have "DEV" environments (seperate from localhost), and sometimes it is a feasible scenario to want to debug IIS on this environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also have to install the remote debugger on the target server if it is not the same machine the debugger is installed on. It can be found on the Visual Studio installation disk.

Answer (score 9):

To Attach the ASPNet worker process to your VS IDE

For IIS 6.0 and above  - attach **w3wp.exe**

For earlier versions - attach **aspnet_wp.exe**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run VS as administrator. Then attach the debugger to the w3wp.exe (there may be more than one). You attach to the w3wp.exe process by choosing "Debug->Attach to process". The shortcut is Alt+d Alt+p.